# Excel - list in two columns each unique-pair from two source columns in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I've been using index, match and countif to list unique values happily for some time, but now I want to list unique pairs from an excel sheet based on two columns of values. For example, if the data is so:

Input

```
> Col. 1   Col. 2
  A        x   
  A        x
  B        x 
  B        y
  B        x
  C        x 
  C        y 
  C        x
```

The unique list of pairs should be:

```
> Col. 1   Col. 2
  A        x   
  B        x 
  B        y
  C        x 
  C        y
```

This seems to be a common suggestion:
=INDEX(!D$4:D$5, MATCH(0, COUNTIF($A$57:$A59,!$C$4:$C$5) * COUNTIF($B$57:$B59, !$D$4:$D$5), 0)),"")
But will not return a value like the pair C and y, in the example, because C and y have appeared already - in different pairs.

I've tried concat (doesn't work inside countif), sumproduct (doesn't seem to like sumproduct(--($A$57:$A59=!$C$4:$C$5), --($B$57:$B59 = !$D$4:$D$5)); and countifs($A$57:$A59,!$C$4:$C$5),$B$57:$B59,!$D$4:$D$5) (returns error).

PS - I know nothing of VB, and for various reasons need a formula approach.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use COUNTIFS:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($A$2:$B$9,MATCH(0,COUNTIFS($D$1:$D1,$A$2:$A$9,$E$1:$E1,$B$2:$B$9),0),1),"")
```

for the first column and

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($A$2:$B$9,MATCH(0,COUNTIFS($D$1:$D1,$A$2:$A$9,$E$1:$E1,$B$2:$B$9),0),2),"")
```

for the second column

entered as an array formula using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>

[image]

Note the formulas will give a spurious extra row if blank cells are included - this can be fixed:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($A$2:$B$9,MATCH(1,(COUNTIFS($G$1:$G1,$A$2:$A$9,$H$1:$H1,$B$2:$B$9)=0)*($A$2:$A$9<>"")*($B$2:$B$9<>""),0),1),"")

=IFERROR(INDEX($A$2:$B$9,MATCH(1,(COUNTIFS($G$1:$G1,$A$2:$A$9,$H$1:$H1,$B$2:$B$9)=0)*($A$2:$A$9<>"")*($B$2:$B$9<>""),0),2),"")
```

Comment: Thanks, appreciated. And, likewise.

Comment: Very much appreciated. The spurious extra row has been a problem of mine for years! To understand this extra logic, could you please clarify - you have switched the match value to 1, so that the index row # will be returned for the first row in the array where a pre-existing pair is NOT counted, and when a value is in both source columns. Does countifs(...)=0 return 1 if nothing is found?

Comment: Yes, precisely that.

Answer (score 2):

Concatenate the two columns (with a distinct delimiter between, say `#` or `|` or `£`or `¬`, to aid splitting later), process that (as for a single column) and then Text to Columns to split back into two.

Comment: Thanks, in this case at least, I couldn't do this as the actual text values are quite complex and don't lend themselves to being split back apart. Perhaps by concatenating as you suggest for the countifs, and then indexing the original might work, but I found this approach was skyrocketing in complexity - for my situation at least.